# Аналог функции $.getJSON в javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как через JavaScript можно заменить эти строки jQuery

```
 $.getJSON("adress", function(data){
     console.log(data)
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как-то так:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), data;
xhr.open('get', 'url', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (~~(xhr.status / 100)) == 2) {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(data);
    }
}
xhr.send(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery довольно сильно абстрагируется от чистого JavaScript. Поэтому прямого аналога такой функции в js нет. Работайте с объектом XmlHttpRequest. Чтобы распарсить json можно использовать JSON.parse(). Это встроенный в язык метод. Поддерживается всеми браузерами начиная с IE8.